# How to display attributes of an object when onChange on select input occurs using SPring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I am using Spring MVC. I am trying to display a list of "Firm" objects. Firm has different attributes including firmName, state, zipcode etc...

The code to display just the firm object (which is the string representation of each firm object in memory) is
**

```
<select name="issuingFirm" id="issuingFirm">
    <c:forEach var="entity" items="${candidateIsssuingFirmList}">
        <option value="${entity}">${entity}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

**

in my Controller I already have the List of firms (`List<Firm>`)

The following method is a utility method which takes the list of firms and put them in to a map so that I can put it latter in a model to display it in my jsp page

```
public static Map getIssuingEntities(List<Firm> firmList) {          

    Map entityData = new HashMap();
    entityData.put("candidateIsssuingFirmList", firmList);

    return entityData;
}
```

In my controller (get method) I use the following code to call the above method and put it in to a model (model is type of ModelMap)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "...", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getIssuerInformationPage(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
```

.
.
.
.

```
List<Firm> firmList = firmRepository.findGroupFirmsByFirm(getFirmOidFromMemberOid(getMemberOid(session)));
model.addAllAttributes(PrivateOfferPlacementUtil.getIssuingEntities(firmList));
...
.
.
}
```

The problem with this code is, it displays just a string of firm object on the jsp page. 
 What I need is display only the firm name and then when the user selects different firm name from the list,I want to display state, zip , and etc ... below it. I can easily replace the getIssuingEntities method to return list of firm names instead of the list object but I will end up only having names. My question is how can I store the list of firm objects and when there is onChange on the select input, I will call the methods on the firm object and display the attributes I wanted?

FYI: The firm object is very big but I need less than 5 attributes from it. Is it possible to use javascript to store the list of firmObjects? How can  I do it without using Ajax when there is an OnChange on the select input. With ajax it might be easy as taking the firm name, do a search of that object and fetch the attributes I wanted. But I dont want to do that.

How can I achieve what I am trying to implement?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add firm name etc in value on your option using delimiter (such as Pipeline | ) :

```
<select name="issuingFirm" id="issuingFirm">
    <c:forEach var="entity" items="${candidateIsssuingFirmList}">
        <option value="${entity.id}|${entity.name}">${entity}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Then you can add on Change event to split that value and show firm name somewhere in your html.